# How to log in separate file per node

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, logging, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community!

In the .ros/log/{cryptic_someting}/  folder I see some nodes create their own log files:
E.g.: controller_spawner-3.log or rqt_robot_steering-5.log

How can I achieve that for my own nodes? - Until now all my log messages are written in the roslaunch.log

Thanks in advance
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363556/how-to-log-in-separate-file-per-node/) by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2020-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using `ROS_INFO` function to display the log message and you can do this by setting `output="log"` to a node in the launch file.

Reference

- http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node
- http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on 2020-10-19**:
It worked thanks. Extra question: Do you know how to set it up that it logs to the separate file AND outputs to the screen?

**Comment by [MadeleineP](https://answers.ros.org/users/61226/madeleinep/) on 2020-10-19**:
Do you mean:   output="log"   ?
There is no 'display' parameter in node.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-10-19**:
@alex_ I'm glad I could help you.
may be you can use the `tee` command.
If you want to have any further interaction, please do so on a separate question page.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-10-19**:
@MadeleineP Thank you for pointing this out. You are right. I have reflected it.

**Comment by [MadeleineP](https://answers.ros.org/users/61226/madeleinep/) on 2020-10-19**:
@Miura, I have added  output="log"  to my launch file, and I receive all of my ROS_INFO messages in rosout.log.  A separate log file for my node is not being created.  However, several other nodes are logging to their own log files.  Is there something else I need to do?  Thanks.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-10-19**:
@MadeleineP You are probably running into the behavior described in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/162786/logging-to-file-and-screen/) that also includes a link to an open bug report.

**Comment by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on 2020-10-20**:
@MadeleineP The answer from miura san worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04) therefore I marked it as correct.